# Keep getting the error message "Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated" can't understand why

Tags: exception, recursion, prolog, successor-arithmetics, instantiation-error

Keep getting the error `Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated` for the multiplication by addition rule I wrote as shown below.

```
mult(_, 0, 0).                                   %base case for multiplying by 0
mult(X, 1, X).                                   % another base case
mult(X, Y, Z) :-
   Y > 1,
   Y1 is Y - 1,
   mult(X, Y1, Z1),
   Z is X + Z1.
```

I am new to Prolog and really struggling with even such simple problems.

Any recommendations for books or online tutorials would be great.

I am running it on SWI-Prolog on Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>I think you got the last two calls reversed. Don't you mean:</strike>

```
mult(X,Y,Z):- Y>1,Y1 is Y-1, Z1 is X+Z, mult(X,Y1,Z1).
```

*Edit:* nevermind that, looked at the code again and it doesn't make sense. I believe your original code is correct.

As for why that error is occuring, I need to know how you're calling the predicate. Can you give an example input?

The correct way of calling your predicate is `mult(+X, +Y, ?Z)`:

```
?- mult(5,0,X).
X = 0

?- mult(5,1,X).
X = 5

?- mult(5,5,X).
X = 25

?- mult(4,4,16).
yes

?- mult(3,3,10).
no
```

etc. Calling it with a free variable in the first two arguments will produce that error, because one of them will be used in the right side of an `is` or in either side of the `<`, and those predicates expect ground terms to succeed.

Comment: the thing is I can't even compile I simply try to load the file into prolog [PA3]. and it gives this error. which is weird I think

Comment: Try renaming your file to lowercase. When Prolog sees `PA3` it interprets it as a variable, that's why it's giving that error. Another option is to use quotes: `['PA3'].` it might work. Other than that, your program is 100% fine! (tested here, no problems at all)

Comment: hahaha thanks I almost went crazy with frustration.. so trivial

Answer (score 4):

In your definition of `mult/3` the first two arguments have to be known. If one of them is still a variable, an instantiation error will occur. Eg. `mult(2, X, 6)` will yield an instantiation error, although `X = 3` is a correct answer ; in fact, the only answer.

There are several options you have:

[successor-arithmetics](/questions/tagged/successor-arithmetics), constraints, or meta-logical predicates.

Here is a starting point with successor arithmetics:

```
add(0,Y,Y).
add(s(X),Y,s(Z)) :- add(X,Y,Z).
```

Another approach would be to use constraints over the integers. YAP and SWI have a [`library(clpfd)`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html) that can be used in a very flexible manner: Both for regular integer computations and the more general constraints. Of course, multiplication is already predefined:

```
?- A * B #= C.
   A*B#=C.
?- A * B #= C, C = 6.
   C = 6, A in -6.. -1\/1..6, A*B#=6, B in -6.. -1\/1..6.
?- A * B #= C, C = 6, A = 2.
   A = 2, B = 3, C = 6.
```

Meta-logical predicates: I cannot recommend this option in which you would use `var/1`, `nonvar/1`, `ground/1` to distinguish various cases and handle them differently. This is so error prone that I have rarely seen a correct program using them.  In fact, even very well known textbooks contain serious errors!